# What is the difference between Public DNS and public IP in AWS ec2?

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, google-public-dns

I found that in ec2 there are two things
public DNS and public IP

> ec2-XX-XXX-190-196.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com

```
 and
```

> xx.255.190.196

Both can access through ssh and ping.

So what are the difference?

Answer (score 4):

[DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) and [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) are two different ways to address hosts. When you address a host using the DNS address it looks up the IP address of that address in a **[name server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Name_servers)**
and contacts that. One simple way to illustrate this is to notice that `ping some-dns-address` will print the IP address in parentheses after the DNS name, and the `dig` command can give you more detail about how the DNS name is configured

(The details are enormously more complicated than this, and describing it in much detail in this space would be futile.)

Comment: THanks, do u know the reason behind why AWS provides two ways to address host? I think Public IP is enough for us

Comment: @KitHo an answer 4 years later, but you probably don't want to spend your time memorizing IP addresses. DNS are much more accessible once you've registered it or provided your own custom one (like www.myownsite.com)